# How can I determine the electrode potential of ethanoic acid redox reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, electrochemistry, kinetics

I'm conducting a research paper on the effect of surface area ratio from anode to cathode and the electrode material on the rate of electrolysis of ethanoic acid by measuring the volume of carbon dioxide collected. In order to determine the material that I am using (so that it is kept constant), I need to determine the electrode potential of ethanoic acid.

If anyone knows of a standard electrode potential for ethanoic acid, that would be great so that I can avoid testing for it experimentally.

Comment: Perhaps this link might help: http://ceae.colorado.edu/~silverst/cven5534/REDOX%20HALF%20REACTIONS.pdf.

Comment: Do you know the chemical equation of the reaction, or at least of the half reaction?